# Null pointer in Retrofit + RxJava error with pojo

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I know guys. Null pointer was already a lot. Honestly, I read all that topics but I can't find a mistake in the code. Please help.

I use regular scheme RxJava + retrofit but got null pointer logs says that mistake in response. Might be problem in model but I checked it. I know I lost something but can't find out what exactly.

Fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /**
     * Main Initialization
     */
    resultsList = new ArrayList<>();
    //adapter = new ListAdapter(resultsList);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_list_detailed);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    //adapter.setClickListener(this);

    /**
     * Checking for internet connection
     */
    if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(getContext())) {
        final ProgressDialog dialog;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.string_getting_json_title));
        dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.string_getting_json_message));
        dialog.show();

        /**
         * Making HTTP request
         */
        ApiService api = RetrofitClient.getApiService();
        Observable.just(api.getPhotosList(getString(R.string.api_key)))
                .map(Call::execute)
                .filter(Response::isSuccessful)
                .map(Response::body)
                .onErrorReturn(throwable -> new ResultsPojo(new ArrayList<>(), 1))
                .doOnError(throwable -> Log.e("ERROR", throwable.getMessage()))
                .map(ResultsPojo::getMovies)
                .doOnNext(list -> {
                    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                        adapter = new ListAdapter(list);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } else Log.d("LISTMOVIES", "Something went wrong!!!");
                }).subscribe();
```

ApiService

```
public interface ApiService {
    @GET("3/movie/popular")
    Call<ResultsPojo> getPhotosList(@Query("api_key") String key);
}
```

MoviesPojo

```
public class MoviesPojo {

    @SerializedName("vote_count")
    @Expose
    private int voteCount;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("video")
    @Expose
    private boolean video;
    @SerializedName("vote_average")
    @Expose
    private double voteAverage;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("popularity")
    @Expose
    private double popularity;
    @SerializedName("poster_path")
    @Expose
    private String posterPath;
    @SerializedName("original_language")
    @Expose
    private String originalLanguage;
    @SerializedName("original_title")
    @Expose
    private String originalTitle;
    @SerializedName("genre_ids")
    @Expose
    private List<Integer> genreIds = null;
    @SerializedName("backdrop_path")
    @Expose
    private String backdropPath;
    @SerializedName("adult")
    @Expose
    private boolean adult;
    @SerializedName("overview")
    @Expose
    private String overview;
    @SerializedName("release_date")
    @Expose
    private String releaseDate;

    public int getVoteCount() {
        return voteCount;
    }

    public void setVoteCount(int voteCount) {
        this.voteCount = voteCount;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean isVideo() {
        return video;
    }

    public void setVideo(boolean video) {
        this.video = video;
    }

    public double getVoteAverage() {
        return voteAverage;
    }

    public void setVoteAverage(double voteAverage) {
        this.voteAverage = voteAverage;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public double getPopularity() {
        return popularity;
    }

    public void setPopularity(double popularity) {
        this.popularity = popularity;
    }

    public String getPosterPath() {
        return posterPath;
    }

    public void setPosterPath(String posterPath) {
        this.posterPath = posterPath;
    }

    public String getOriginalLanguage() {
        return originalLanguage;
    }

    public void setOriginalLanguage(String originalLanguage) {
        this.originalLanguage = originalLanguage;
    }

    public String getOriginalTitle() {
        return originalTitle;
    }

    public void setOriginalTitle(String originalTitle) {
        this.originalTitle = originalTitle;
    }

    public List<Integer> getGenreIds() {
        return genreIds;
    }

    public void setGenreIds(List<Integer> genreIds) {
        this.genreIds = genreIds;
    }

    public String getBackdropPath() {
        return backdropPath;
    }

    public void setBackdropPath(String backdropPath) {
        this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
    }

    public boolean isAdult() {
        return adult;
    }

    public void setAdult(boolean adult) {
        this.adult = adult;
    }

    public String getOverview() {
        return overview;
    }

    public void setOverview(String overview) {
        this.overview = overview;
    }

    public String getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }

    public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) {
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }

}
```

ResultsPojo

```
public class ResultsPojo {

    @SerializedName("page")
    @Expose
    private int page;
    @SerializedName("total_results")
    @Expose
    private int totalResults;
    @SerializedName("total_pages")
    @Expose
    private int totalPages;
    @SerializedName("moviesPojos")
    @Expose
    private List<MoviesPojo> moviesPojos;

    public ResultsPojo(List<MoviesPojo> results, int page){
        this.moviesPojos = results;
        this.page = page;
    }

    public int getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(int page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    public int getTotalResults() {
        return totalResults;
    }

    public void setTotalResults(int totalResults) {
        this.totalResults = totalResults;
    }

    public int getTotalPages() {
        return totalPages;
    }

    public void setTotalPages(int totalPages) {
        this.totalPages = totalPages;
    }

    public List<MoviesPojo> getMovies() {
        return moviesPojos;
    }

    public void setMoviesPojos(List<MoviesPojo> moviesPojos) {
        this.moviesPojos = moviesPojos;
    }

}
```

Adapter

```
private List<MoviesPojo> resultList;
private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

public ListAdapter(List<MoviesPojo> data) {
    this.resultList = data;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_banner, parent, false);
    return new ListViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ListViewHolder holder, int position) {

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    //TODO Здесь мы должны получить список ссылок для изображений
    return resultList.size();
}


public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView mImageBanner;

    public ListViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mImageBanner = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_banner_image);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
    }
}

        // convenience method for getting data at click position
    //    public String getItem(int id) {
    //        return resultList.get(id);
    //    }


public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

Error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.borisruzanov.popularmovies, PID: 10947
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.borisruzanov.popularmovies/com.borisruzanov.popularmovies.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.borisruzanov.popularmovies.adapters.ListAdapter.setClickListener(com.borisruzanov.popularmovies.adapters.ListAdapter$ItemClickListener)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.borisruzanov.popularmovies.adapters.ListAdapter.setClickListener(com.borisruzanov.popularmovies.adapters.ListAdapter$ItemClickListener)' on a null object reference
                  at com.borisruzanov.popularmovies.ListFragment.onCreateView(ListFragment.java:51)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1428)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3248)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3200)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:195)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:597)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1248)
                  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6679)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609
```

Thank you very much for your time!!! +1 to karma

Comment: post your error !

Comment: @Boris Ruzanov please share the error message...

Comment: Looks like the ListAdapter reference is null because its initialization is commented out in the code?

Comment: The traceback you posted says that you're adapter is `null` when you try to call `setOnClickListener` on it. Since the code you posted has that part commented out - `//adapter.setClickListener(this);` - we can only assume that the problem is something else and not the `NullPointerException` or you accidentally posted the wrong code and the problem is in fact that the adapter is `null` and you have to find out why.

Comment: in your interface **ApiService** , why your return type of your method is Call , and not Observable ?